# Buddypress register page pulling wrong template

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have created a register page and tried to set a template for it by selecting the template from the dropdown in the right column ie: Page attributes->template (dropdown). When I view the register page the form is displaying correctly but it isn't using the template I set for the rest of the content. I can tell that it is instead using page.php from this snippet I used where it should be using template-other.php

```
function show_template() {

   global $template;
   print_r($template);

}

add_action('wp_footer', 'show_template');
```

The funny thing is that if I change the URL to a capital ie: from example.com/register to example.com/Register then it uses the right template but the buddy press form doesn't show up. But if I use example.com/register then the form shows up but it doesn't use the template I set. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Buddypress has it's own register template. Check one of this file : plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/registration/register.php or plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/register.php.

Comment: yeah, I am using that but I want my branded header and footer. I have actually added the register file to my own structure and left it completely empty for testing and that removes the form but my header and footer are still there but the wrong ones.

Comment: Create a folder insider your theme like this : buddypress/members/register.php and put register.php file there

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I even made the file empty to test and I can see it is using that file but still adding content from page.php for some reason.

Comment: Can you please share screenshot if possible

Comment: What would you like a screenshot of?

Comment: Screenshot of the page as well as file

Comment: Added pic of the structure inside of my theme and some code from register.php. Hope that helps?

Comment: You have checked by adding get_header() function in register.php file?

Comment: Just tried adding those and it still doesn't work :(